# C Returned char from GetSaveFileName() contains null characters

Tags: c++, char, savefiledialog

I'm using the following code to get the filepath to save to for use with tinyxml2:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;

char szFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn); 
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
ofn.lpstrFilter = (LPCWSTR)L"XML Files (*.xml)\0*.xml\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFileName;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
ofn.lpstrDefExt = (LPCWSTR)L"xml";
GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
```

This works fine and displays the Dialog box however when I look up the returned value in szFileName it seems to contain many null characters:

```
szFileName  0x0026f5b0 "C"  char[0x00000104]
[0x00000000]    0x43 'C'    char
[0x00000001]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000002]    0x3a ':'    char
[0x00000003]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000004]    0x5c '\\'   char
[0x00000005]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000006]    0x61 'a'    char
[0x00000007]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000008]    0x73 's'    char
[0x00000009]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x0000000a]    0x64 'd'    char
[0x0000000b]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x0000000c]    0x61 'a'    char
[0x0000000d]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x0000000e]    0x73 's'    char
[0x0000000f]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000010]    0x64 'd'    char
[0x00000011]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000012]    0x61 'a'    char
[0x00000013]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000014]    0x73 's'    char
[0x00000015]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000016]    0x2e '.'    char
[0x00000017]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x00000018]    0x78 'x'    char
[0x00000019]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x0000001a]    0x6d 'm'    char
[0x0000001b]    0x00 '\0'   char
[0x0000001c]    0x6c 'l'    char
```

This when passed into tinyxml2 ends up saving a file with which the name is 1 character long, and the first char in szFileName.

Why would it be adding in these null characters after each character?

Comment: `(LPWSTR)szFileName` is a very very very very very very very very very very very very bad thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `GetSaveFileNameW` instead of `GetSaveFileNameA`. Declare `szFileName` as array of `TCHAR` (or `WCHAR`).

The name `GetSaveFileName` will resolve to the name `GetSaveFileNameW` or `GetSaveFileNameA` depending on the `#define` in your code (or project settings). By default it defines `_UNICODE` ("wide charaters") in modern Visual Studio versions.

If you pass it on to another library that expects a certain character set, you may have to convert using `WideCharToMultiByte` or related functions.

Also: don't forcibly coerce one type into an incompatible different type like you do with `szFileName` (being `char[MAX_PATH]`) and `(LPWSTR)`.

Comment: To expand on this, `GetSaveFileName` is a macro that will resolve to either `GetSaveFileNameA` or `GetSaveFileNameW` depending on your build settings.  This is why you should use `TCHAR` because that will also change with your build settings.

Comment: I saw the "This post has been edited" pop-up as I was mousing over the "Add Comment" button.

Comment: Thanks, I was following a forum thread on a different site which gave the example I posted which I was playing around with - obviously wasn't a good start judging by comments here! Thanks for the insight into character sets - I've now got it working as intended!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no professional of the Win32 API, but :

```
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFileName;
```

You are using a [LPWSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx), which is a "32-bit pointer to a string of 16-bit Unicode characters". That means each character is encoded over two bytes. Since ASCII character values fit on a single byte, I'm going to assume the second one is always going to be set to 0.